# How come I can decode a UTF-8 byte string to ISO8859-1 and back again without any UnicodeEncodeError/UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, utf-8, iso-8859-1

How come the following works without any errors in Python?

```
>>> '你好'.encode('UTF-8').decode('ISO8859-1')
'ä½\xa0å¥½'
>>> _.encode('ISO8859-1').decode('UTF-8')
'你好'
```

I would have expected it to fail with a UnicodeEncodeError or UnicodeDecodeError

Is there some property of ISO8859-1 and UTF-8 such that I can take any UTF-8 encoded string and decode it to a ISO8859-1 string, which can later be reversed to get the original UTF-8 string?

I'm working with an older database that only supports the ISO8859-1 character set. It seems like the developers were able to store Chinese and other languages in this database by decoding UTF-8 encoded strings into ISO8859-1, and storing the resulting garbage string in the database. Downstream systems which query this database then have to encode the garbage string in ISO8859-1 and then decode the result with UTF-8 to get the correct string.

I would have assumed that such a process would not work at all.

What am I missing?

---

Answer (score 5):

The special property of ISO-8859-1 is that the 256 characters it represents correspond 1:1 with the first 256 Unicode code points, so byte 00h decodes to U+0000, and byte FFh decodes to U+00FF.

So if you *encode* as UTF-8 and *decode* as ISO-8859-1 you get a Unicode string made up of code points whose values match the UTF-8 bytes encoded:

```py
>>> s = '你好'
>>> s.encode('utf8').hex()
'e4bda0e5a5bd'
>>> s.encode('utf8').decode('iso-8859-1')
'ä½\xa0å¥½'
>>> for c in u:
...  print(f'{c} U+{ord(c):04X}')
...
ä U+00E4   # Unicode code points are the same as the bytes of UTF-8.
½ U+00BD
  U+00A0
å U+00E5
¥ U+00A5
½ U+00BD
>>> u.encode('iso-8859-1').hex()  # transform back to bytes.
'e4bda0e5a5bd'
>>> u.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf8')   # and decode to UTF-8 again.
'你好'
```

Any 8-bit encoding that has a representation for all 256 bytes would also work, it just wouldn't be a 1:1 mapping.  Code Page 1256 is one such encoding:

```py
>>> for c in s.encode('utf8').decode('cp1256'):
...  print(f'{c} U+{ord(c):04X}')
...
ن U+0646   # This would still .encode('cp1256') back to byte E4, for example
½ U+00BD
  U+00A0
ه U+0647
¥ U+00A5
½ U+00BD
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no special property of ISO8859-1, but one property common on many 8-bit encoding: they accept all bytes from 0 to 255.

So you `decode('ISO8859-1')` is just transforming bytes into 256 characters (and control codes) in a unique way. Then you do the contrary action, so you lose nothing.

This happens with most of old 8-bit encoding: they should just have a corresponding Unicode codepoint (because Python expect strings to be Unicode strings).

Note: really ISO8859-1 is special with Unicode: the first 256 codepoint of Unicode correspond to the Latin-1 characters (with same number). But this doesn't matter much on your experiment.

Comment: But `你` does not exist in ISO8859-1 - how can that **not** be a decoding error? I'd understand that if we were decoding from UTF-8 to **bytes** explicitly.

Comment: The `encode` UTF-8 is transforming the string into a byte sequence (one or more bytes per unicode character). Then every single byte is interpreted as Latin-1. When you *encode* you are transforming data into byte sequences (and no information about original encoding). Just "random" bytes.